# A simple metric question

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In their article [Killing vector fields of standard static spacetimes](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.4692), Dobarro and Unal derived the following simple identity.

> Note that if $h:I→R$ is smooth and $Y,Z∈ {\frak{X}}\left(I\right)$, then
>    $$L_{h∂_t}g_I(Y,Z) =Y(h)g_I(Z,∂_t) +Z(h)g_I(Y,∂_t)$$
>   where $I$ is an an open connected interval of the real line $\bf R$ furnished by the metric $g_I=-dt^2$ and $dt^2$ is the Euclidean metric.

My question is(it seems to be **silly**):
Is the following simplification of the identity right?
$$\begin{align}
L_{h∂_t}g_I(Y,Z) &=Y(h)g_I(Z,∂_t) +Z(h)g_I(Y,∂_t)\\
&=\dot{h}g_I(Z,Y) +\dot{h}g_I(Y,Z)\\
&=2\dot{h}g_I(Y,Z)
\end{align}$$ If it is right, the authors didn't use it why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe not notice.

Comment: @ploosu2 so it is correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplification is correct. It shouldn't be too surprising to find such a simple expression - since $I$ is one-dimensional, every $(0,2)$-tensor on it is the product of $g_I$ with some smooth function.

I'm unsure why the authors didn't make this simplification - perhaps because the equation they give is slightly more general, while your simplification relies on the fact that $Y,Z$ must be multiples of $\partial_t$ in one dimension. Perhaps they just missed it.